# Nginx downloads php instead of running it

Tags: php, linux, nginx, fastcgi

Iv'e setup an Nginx php server on a linux REHL machine.
When accessing html files all goes well, but trying to access php file, the file is downloaded instead of being executed.

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

...and this is the server block:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  {mywebsitename};

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/{mywebsitename}/;
    }

    location /ngx_status_2462 {
      stub_status on;
      access_log   off;
      allow all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
#                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/{mywebsitename}$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So this is small point, you wrote `root   /usr/share/nginx/html/{mywebsitename}/;` so I assumed `{mywebsitename}` doesn't contain a trailing `/`, so `{mywebsitename}$fastcgi_script_name;` should be `{mywebsitename}/$fastcgi_script_name;` right ? (added a slash)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had this exact same problem. I was using Ubuntu 12.04 and Linux Mint 14 so different OS but likely to have the same issues.

A couple of issues may happening. Firstly, you need to have php5-fpm installed (FastCGI Process Manager). I was trying to run it with my standard version of PHP but it was not working - http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php

I also had Apache installed, and even if it weren't running it must have had some conflict because once I uninstalled Apache I was able to execute the PHP files.

I would also look at this line

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

And consider changing it to

```
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Here is a detailed guide to installation of Nginx and PHP5-FPM for RHEL (and other OS's)

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: That was that. Thanks alot!

Comment: Uninstalling apache2 was what fixed it for me, after that, PHP scripts executed instead of downloaded ... I wonder apache2 somehow fiddled with MIME types or something...

Comment: An alternative to uninstalling apache2:  When the root serving directory (`/var/www/html` for me) was the same for both nginx and apache2, nginx would download the php file (even if apache wasn't running, just like you).  However, moving nginx's root directory to a different directory (I created one at `/var/www/nginx/`) caused nginx to function correctly.

Answer (score 9):

It might be because of the mimetype you're sending:

```
default_type  application/octet-stream;
```

See: http://mimeapplication.net/octet-stream

Comment: Ran into this problem but only for the root URL. Spent 2-3 hours trying to fix this and finally came across your answer. If I could I'd give you all the upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the user to nginx instead of apache in this file a/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
;user = apache
user = nginx
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
;group = apache
group = nginx
```

and of course restart service php-fpm restart and service nginx restart

Answer (score 1):

Comment out `default_type  application/octet-stream;`