# Nginx rewrite equivalent of apache rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to change the configuration on my new Nginx server so it matches my current Apache settings.
At the moment I am using this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have found a converter that could "translate" this into the Nginx equivalent. I have tried the following:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?url=$1 break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

But when I try to set a url query like this http://domain.tld/something my php file gets returned and downloaded and that ain't supposed to happen.

What I expect to happen is when a url like http://domain.tld/something is entered it gets treated like http://domain.tld/index.php?url=something

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Apache, nginx doesn't come out-of-the-box ready to run PHP. You need to setup a handler to deal with php files, otherwise nginx will serve them up just like any regular file.

See: [Nginx downloads php instead of running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103328/nginx-downloads-php-instead-of-running-it)

Also: review the [NGINX documentation on using fast-cgi to run php](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI).

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for the reply. I got the downloading part of the script working. I turned out to be an error in some other code. However my rewrite issue still remains

Comment: @madsobel the NGINX rewrite is fine, have you cleared your browser's cache?