# nginx - rewrite js file with php file

Tags: nginx

with apache I use a file config.php to rewrite a file config.js based on domain, config.js contains placeholders which are replaced by `RewriteRule` directive, this is .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /foo
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule config.js config.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

When i go into URL production.com/foo/config.js i see some values, instead into develop.com/foo/config.js i see other values, defined into config.php

Now i need move to nginx but i don't understand how to replicate the apache rule, i tried:

```
location /foo {
  alias /src/www/foo;
  index index.html;
  rewrite config.js config.php break;
  }
```

But have internal server error

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I write about `last` instead of `break` but didn't change it in a config code block. Updated an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nginx URIs starts with slash. Using `rewrite config.js config.php` you are rewriting an URI from `/foo/config.js` to `config.php`. That URI cannot be processed by nginx causing internal server error.

First argument of `rewrite` directive is always treated as a regex where dot matched any symbol. So your `rewrite` rule would match any string containing `config*js` substring. I don't think it is what you really want.

Second argument of `rewrite` directive is a whole new URI, not a substitution part of the string. To make a substitution use something like `rewrite ^(.*)old-string(.*)$ $1new-string$2`.

Since you are rewriting your request to PHP script you should force nginx to process new URI with a location where your PHP-FPM handler is defined. To do it you should use `last` flag instead of `break` one with the `rewrite` directive.

Summing all of this, you need something like

```
location /foo {
    alias /src/www/foo;
    index index.html;
    rewrite ^/foo/config\.js$ /foo/config.php last;
}
```

One more note. As nginx documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the root directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

so it would be better to use `root /src/www;` instead of `alias /src/www/foo;` within this `location` block if that `foo` substrings are really equal.

Comment: Thanks for reply, in this way when i go to http://example,com/foo/config.js i see the file config.php

Comment: @hellb0y77 So you do not set up nginx to work with PHP-FPM (or any other PHP handler) yet? You should have php-fpm installed on your server and a special `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` defined to use it (this is the most common approach, there are other choices, [NGINX Unit](https://unit.nginx.org/) for example). Default nginx config should have an example for using PHP-FPM (commented by default). This is out of the scope of your question, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103328/nginx-downloads-php-instead-of-running-it) one.

Comment: nginx work with php-fpm, I've tried to place a phpinfo file at the same path of config.php and work.

Comment: @hellb0y77 Do you have `rewrite ... last;`, not the `rewrite ... break;`? Maybe your browser cached the response?

Comment: yes `rewrite ^/foo/config.js$ /foo/config.php last;`

Comment: @hellb0y77 The only possible reason I can imagine is some other regex matching (`location ~ ...`), exact matching (`location = ...`) or "do-not-check-regex-if-match" (`location ^~ ...`) location takes priority over `location ~ \.php { ... }` with this URI (`/foo/config.php`). Otherwise it should work as expected.